# angularjs ng-show does not work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using below code within a loop

```
"content": '<input id="txt' + $scope.response1[i].id + '" type="text" value="' + $scope.response1[i].subject + '" onclick="this.focus()"><i ng-if="('+$scope.response1[i].priority===undefined+')" class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="color:'+getDemandColor($scope.response1[i].priority)+';"></i>',
```

The problem is when $scope.response1[i].priority is equal to P1, the code `<i ng-show="('+$scope.response1[i].priority===undefined+')" class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="color:'+getDemandColor($scope.response1[i].priority)+';"></i>'` is replaced by "false". So in my UI, i am getting the input box having text as false.

i replaced ng-show by ng-hide and later by ng-if and same behavior is replaced.
i am expecting that if valid priority comes, then a star icon will be shown. if no priority is there, then nothing will be shown.

I could not find out why ng-show/ng-hide/ng-if are showing false and that too the entire code within  tags.

Can you please help. Thanks in advance.

===

Added more code to show how it is used

```
  $scope.dataItem.add({
    "id": $scope.response1[i].id,
    "group": $scope.response1[i].subCapabilityName,
    "content": '<input id="txt' + $scope.response1[i].id + '" type="text" value="' + $scope.response1[i].subject + '" onclick="this.focus()"><i ng-hide="'+$scope.response1[i].priority===undefined+'" class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="color:'+getDemandColor($scope.response1[i].priority)+';"></i>',
    "start": $scope.response1[i].startDate.toString().substring(0, $scope.response1[i].startDate.indexOf('T')),
    "end": $scope.response1[i].endDate.substring(0, $scope.response1[i].endDate.indexOf('T')),
    "type": 'range',
    "className": tmp1,
    "title": (!$scope.response1[i].description ? $scope.response1[i].subject : $scope.response1[i].description)
  });
```

This code is used by a JS library.

Comment: removed brackets. but the same response is coming.

Comment: can you show some more code, what are you doing with this content.

Comment: Please read the documentation about binding controller properties to the view, then you'll know how to do it

Comment: Thanks Gitesh, Added more code as part of the question

Comment: how are you using this dataItem object?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the issue by not using ng-show/ng-hide as shown below.

```
            "content": !$scope.response1[i].priority? 
            '<input id="txt' + $scope.response1[i].id + '" type="text" value="' + $scope.response1[i].subject + '" onclick="this.focus()">':
             '<input id="txt' + $scope.response1[i].id + '" type="text" value="' + $scope.response1[i].subject + '" onclick="this.focus()"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="color:'+getDemandColor($scope.response1[i].priority)+';"></i>',
```